# How does tf.reshape() work internally ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape

I'm trying to understand how tf.reshape works. Let's have an example:

```
embeddings = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[N0,N1])
M_2D = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[N0,None])
M_3D = tf.reshape(M_2D, [-1,N0,1])
weighted_embeddings = tf.multiply(embeddings, M_3D)
```

Here I have a 2D tensor M_2D whose columns represent coefficients for the N0 embeddings of dimension N1. I want to create a 3D tensor where each column of M_2D is placed in the first dimension of M_3D, and columns are keep in the same order. My final goal is to create a 3D tensor of 2D embeddings, each weighted by the columns of M_2D.

How can I be sure that reshape actually place each column in the new dimension of M_3D. Is it possible that it places the rows instead ? Is there somewhere in tensorflow documentation a clear explanation on the internal working process of tf.reshape, particularly when -1 is provided ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tensor before and after `tf.reshape` have the **same flatten order**.

In tensorflow runtime, a Tensor is consists of raw data(byte array), shape, and dtype, `tf.reshape` only change shape, with raw data and dtype not changed. `-1` or `None` in `tf.reshape` means that this value can be calculated.

For example,

```
# a tensor with 6 elements, with shape [3,2]
a = tf.constant([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]) 
# reshape tensor to [2, 3, 1], 2 is calculated by 6/3/1
b = tf.reshape(a, [-1, 3, 1])
```

In this example, `a` and `b` have the same flatten order, namely `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `a` has the shape `[3,2]`, its value is `[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]`, `b` has the shape `[2,3,1]`, its value is `[[[1],[2],[3]],[[4],[5],[6]]]`.